# Why does my OSX 10.7+ application leak memory when XCode force-quits it, even when all smart pointers garbage collect successfully?

Tags: xcode, macos, memory-leaks, osx-lion

While developing a framework in XCode, I experienced an unusual error in which my applications would leak memory whenever they were force quit by XCode via the "stop" button. With some careful use of [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) I determined that all dynamic memory created by my framework was being successfully garbage collected from the heap. All the types on the stack had valid destructors.

The line that hung up the application was a null-reference *at the very end of main()*. As far as I knew, there was no memory being allocated after that point, and no way for memory to then leak. After getting the SIGABRT signal, I would hit "Stop" and my faulty build would quit. A check with a few profilers revealed my RAM being sucked into thin air.

Answer (score 0):

The key was OSX Lion's helpful window that popped up when re-running (the same build) after a force quit. It said something along the lines of "Do you want to try to restore the windows of this application which force quit last time?"

After some digging, I found out that my new OS upgrade (Lion) had been caching the last state of my faulty application via its shiny new "Restore Windows" functionality. Whether I restored the application or not, the memory used by the state cache was piling up. I [turned it off](http://www.cultofmac.com/148775/stop-the-restore-windows-feature-three-different-ways-os-x-tips/) and now I don't have any memory leaks ... for now.

I'm not sure why OSX was creating a new state representation for each of my builds. For other applications in my /Applications directory, there seems to be only one cached state (for each window open on application quit/force quit). However, it seems like a new state is being created for each build in XCode. It might have to do with the way individual builds are ID'd in XCode, **or I might be totally wrong about the entire OT.**